# Entering Multiple Instances of a CakePHP Model on 1 Page with an AJAX Dialog Box

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I would like to allow a user of my CakePHP website application to enter a bunch of items where each item is 1 instance of a model. How would I do that?

To make things extra complicated, some of the entries might require showing a little hovering dialog box that asks for some text, validates the response, and sends it into a database before closing. I plan to use [Keep Validation and Errors in the same jQuery Dialog Box - CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998371/keep-validation-and-errors-in-the-same-jquery-dialog-box-cakephp) as a model for that.

Comment: CakePHP doesn't use Model instances *per row*. CakePHP *'Models'* handle both *recordsets* and *individual* records. Record *sets* are represented by Associative arrays, not by multiple 'instances' of a Model. If you worked with other frameworks before, this may seem *odd* (it is), and the CakePHP team is working on a massive overhaul of the Models for CakePHP 3.x. If you need to create a Form/Page to edit or add multiple records, have a look at this part of the documentation [Field naming conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate, the solution is to do something like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Modelname.0.fieldname');
echo $this->Form->input('Modelname.1.fieldname');
```

Then, to save everything in the controller, call SaveAll() as described at http://nik.chankov.net/2010/09/08/cakephp-saveall-quick-tip/:

```
$this->Article->saveAll($data['Article']);
```

And don't try to use:

```
$this->Article->saveAll($data);
```